# How does the splitting point in cross-validation affect the performance estimate?

Tags: cross-validation, bias-variance-tradeoff

I want to use simple cross-validation to estimate the performance of a model.

There are different ways how I can split the data into a training and test dataset.

Let's consider three cases:

a) 50% training, 50% testing data

b) 20% training, 80% testing data

c) 80% training, 20% testing data

How does the splitting point affect bias/variance?

Is it fair to say that in comparison to a), b) has a high bias but low variance and c) has a low bias but high variance?

Comment: Option-b doesn't seem to be a cross-validation. And, in option-c do you have 5 folds, or is it just one split 80-20? If so, it's not CV as well.